# Change privacy setting in Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

We have an open Facebook group. Accidentally one of the admins changed the setting into "secret". We want to change back our privacy setting to "open". Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

If your group has more than 250 people, you can't change back from secret...

Look [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/286027304749263)

> When a group hits 250 people, you can only change an Open group to Closed or Secret, and a Closed group to Secret. You won't be able to change the privacy again after this.

Comment: Is it no other way  to reopen this group?we have 1500 plus member and we wanted to be a open group.? Thank u and god bless

Comment: Not as far as Facebook terms...